# JDK17 throws an error /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found

Tags: java, centos5, openjdk-17

I am in process of upgrading my project from 1.8 to jdk 17. Everything works well on Ubuntu 18.

While attempting to compile the project with JDK17, I get following error:

```
Error: dl failure on line 542
Error: failed /****/apps/java/jdk-17.0.3.1/lib/server/libjvm.so, because 
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by /****/apps/java/jdk-17.0.3.1/lib/server/libjvm.so)
```

OS version: CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
Open JDK version: jdk-17.0.2
Oracle JDK version: jdk-17.0.3.1

Any ways to get around this issue without upgrading the OS version as we cannot upgrade OS for a while.

Comment: "CentOS release 5.11" That is an old OS. You'll need to install glibc 2.6 on it. You can build it all locally, but it is going to be a world of pain. Have you considered a docker/container solution?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/451386/glibc-2-6-on-centos-5-8 that was asked nearly 10 years ago. The os you are using was outdated 10 years ago. Why do you want to leave java 1.8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448265/statically-linking-to-a-dynamic-library-glibc may be something you could dig into